# How to make notification appear only in top?

Tags: android, notifications

So I have this code

```
public class notif extends Activity {
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final NotificationManager mgr=(NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"New Problem ",System.currentTimeMillis());
        note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this,list.class), 0);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this,"Problem Occured","Click to see the problem",i);
        mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID,note);
}
```

This code is about making notifications but i want it to just appear on my notification on top an not opening any page at first so it's like the notification can appear in the main menu without opening any page at first like.the sms notification that appear on top only without having to see the entire sms until we click the notification so can someone help me with this? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Create a class NotificationAlert and paste the code below there:

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;

    public class NotificationAlert extends Activity {

        private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notification_alert);

            /*********** Create notification ***********/

            final NotificationManager mgr=
                (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,
                                                            "Android Example Status message!",
                                                            System.currentTimeMillis());

            // This pending intent will open after notification click
            PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                    new Intent(this, NotifyMessage.class),
                                                    0);

            note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                                    "This is the android example notification message", i);

            //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
            //note.number=2;
            mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);


        }
    }

Create a class NotifyMessage  and paste the code below there:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotifyMessage extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView txt=new TextView(this);

        txt.setText("Activity after click on notification");
        setContentView(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okies its better to try in a new project :)

Comment: I try it and it works but it still go to the content view of the layout first and then show the notifications still thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: can pls make your problem little more clear ? is there any examples that working as you want it to be

Comment: That's the problem I never find any examples that working like what i want, i want the notification to appear without entering any page at all at first so like when in main menu then it's only the notification that appear and i still can see the main menu,not like what i try that the notification appear but the screen also has to go blank at first,i think it's because the setContentView(R.layout.notification_alert); but when i try to remove it it still must go to the blank page first.

Comment: I think u can set the default content in the main menu in one layout and when the notification come you can pragmatically set the visibility of that layout to "gone" and the desired content that has to be displayed set in another layout which is initially set invisible and made visible once the notification appears. If  its not clear pls revert me so that i can make it clear.

Comment: the layout which i have mentioned above is not XML file its relative or linear layout inside the XML file R.layout.notification_alert.

Comment: Thank you I think I know what do you mean by set the visibility to gone and then making the other layout set from invisible to visible,so can you show me the code to change that visibility?cause i can set it to gone or to invisible but i can't change it after that,thank you before and sorry for late comment.

Comment: No i already try it but it still show another screen,i think my problem isn't clear yet, so perhaps i can give an example like notification of an sms, when sms comes to your android it will only show you the notification, even when your phone is locked, even when you unlocked your phone you still see your main screen and then you drop down your notification and when you click it that when you can see the message, i think that is the way that i want my notification to appear. is that clear enough for you to help me?

Comment: I guess its not possible to show the the notification when the screen is unlock in kitkat but the same is possible in android L., updated version of kitkat. just google about that. and the 2nd stage let me just check it once more.

Comment: if possible can you just make a picture representation of what exactly u want

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=4405822921621&set=a.4405822481610.1073741826.1770118077&type=3&theater this is the link for the photo that I upload I want it to be like that so perhaps you know how to make them?just like notification when you got a message sort of,thank you before.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know now that i have to use service and this is the code for making that service hope it helps other

```
public class servicenotif extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "servicenotif";
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;
private String url="Your URL";
SharedPreferences mPrefs;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {

     //Untuk bikin alarm yang ngecek ke database setiap 30 detik
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, servicenotif.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i,0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);


    }
 @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
     //buat preference
     new LoginAsyncTask().execute();






    //Note: You can start a new thread and use it for long background processing from here.
    }
 class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String response = "";
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        //step2
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {





                //publishProgress(190);


                mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 //ngambil data preference
                 String txtTransID=mPrefs.getString("tid", "");
                 if(txtTransID.equals("")){
                     txtTransID="0";
                 }
                 int t=Integer.valueOf(txtTransID);
                 //membuat notifikasi yang muncul apabila ada problem dan hanya muncul lagi apabila ada problem baru
                 JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("Your URL");
                 JSONObject js = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("Your URL");
                 JSONObject j = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("Your URL");
                 try{

                        JSONArray  makanan = json.getJSONArray("makanan");

                        for(int i=0;i<makanan.length();i++){
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            JSONObject jsonobj = makanan.getJSONObject(i);
                            map.put("id",jsonobj.getString("Status"));
                            //mengecek status yang berubah dari nol menjadi 1
                            if(jsonobj.getString("Status").equals("1")){
                                JSONArray aku=js.getJSONArray("makanan");
                                for(int a=0;a<aku.length();a++)
                                {
                                    HashMap<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    JSONObject jsb = aku.getJSONObject(a);
                                    mp.put("take", jsb.getString("Taken"));
                                    //mengecek Taken yang belum diambil
                                    if(jsb.getString("Taken").equals("null")){

                                        JSONArray tid=j.getJSONArray("makanan");
                                        for(int Ti=0;Ti<tid.length();Ti++){
                                            HashMap<String,String> trans=new HashMap<String, String>();
                                            JSONObject jo=tid.getJSONObject(Ti);
                                            trans.put("trans", jo.getString("Trans_ID"));
                                            int TID;
                                            //mengecek Trans_ID yang ditambahkan apa ada yang baru atau tidak
                                            if(jo.getString("Trans_ID").equals("")){
                                                TID=0;
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                TID=Integer.valueOf(jo.getString("Trans_ID"));
                                            }
                                            if(t<TID){
                                                Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                                editor.putString("tid", jo.getString("Trans_ID"));
                                                editor.commit();
                                        map.put("nama", jsonobj.getString("Andon_Type"));
                                        map.put("harga",    jsonobj.getString("Line"));
                                        String andon=jsonobj.getString("Andon_Type");
                                        String line=jsonobj.getString("Line");
                                        NotificationManager mgr=(NotificationManager)servicenotif.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                        Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"New Problem ",System.currentTimeMillis());
                                        note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                                        PendingIntent b=PendingIntent.getActivity(servicenotif.this, 0,new Intent(servicenotif.this,list2.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);          
                                        note.setLatestEventInfo(servicenotif.this,"Problem Occured","Click to see the list of problem",b);
                                        note.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
                                        mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID,note);
                                            }
                                            //membuat notifikasi muncul lagi apabila data di reset
                                            else if(t>TID){
                                                Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                                                editor.putString("tid", "");
                                                editor.commit();
                                            }
                                        }



                            }
                                }

                        }

                 }



                 }




                 catch(JSONException e){


                 }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(190);
            return null;
        }
        //last step
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {









            //dialog.cancel();


        }

        private void onCreate(Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // biasanya untuk progress download
            int nilai = values[0];
            // didapat dari publish progress

        }
//step1
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // buat bikin dialog loading
            /*dialog = ProgressDialog.show(list.this, "Loading",
                    "Please wait..");*/
            super.onPreExecute();


        }
        public void write(String fileName){
            BufferedWriter bw=null;
            try{
                bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }


    }

 private void getRequest(String Url2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Penghandelan Gagal !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

}
private String request(HttpResponse response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result = "";

    try {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        result = str.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = "Error";
    }
    return result;
}
@Override
//untuk logout mematikan notifikasi dan alarm supaya tidak menjalankan service lagi
    public void onDestroy() {
    NotificationManager mgr=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.cancelAll();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Log out successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,new Intent(this,servicenotif.class), 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(i);

    }
```

Hope this will help